# How snmp agent retrives data

Tags: linux, networking, snmp, snmpd

I am trying to understand how snmp works. I understand the concept of MIB and OID, but I don't understand how the data is retrieved one the manager asks for it.

In my online research, I have seen that the agent is not "checking" the data every time a request is made, but that it is bringing it from somewhere. I am trying to understand where this place is - a file? the snmpd memory? or somewhere in the kernel which I can't see?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758054/where-to-begin-with-snmp-agent-implementation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to begin with SNMP agent implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758054/where-to-begin-with-snmp-agent-implementation)

Comment: That’s very agent specific and OID specific. Keep in mind that snmpd can be extended in different ways, so not all objects are handled the same way.